# Data on one row by ID

Tags: r

I have a data frame with one id column and several other column grouped by couple and i'm trying to put all the data for a same id on one row. ID's do not appear the same number of times each.

My data looks like this :

```
df <- data.frame(id=sample(1:4, 12, T), vpcc1=1:12, hpcc1=rnorm(12), vpcc2=1:12, hpcc2=rnorm(12), vpcc3=1:12, hpcc3=rnorm(12))
df
##    id vpcc1       hpcc1 vpcc2       hpcc2 vpcc3       hpcc3
## 1   1     1  0.04632267     1 -0.37404379     1  0.90711353
## 2   4     2  0.50383152     2  0.06075954     2  0.30690284
## 3   1     3  1.52450117     3 -1.21539925     3 -1.12411614
## 4   1     4 -0.50624871     4 -0.75988364     4 -0.47970608
## 5   3     5  1.64610863     5  0.03445275     5 -0.18895338
## 6   1     6  0.22019099     6 -0.32101883     6  1.29375822
## 7   2     7 -0.10041807     7 -0.17351799     7 -0.03767921
## 8   2     8  0.81683565     8  0.62449158     8  0.50474787
## 9   2     9 -0.46891269     9  1.07743469     9 -0.55539149
## 10  1    10  0.69736549    10 -0.08573679    10  0.28025325
## 11  3    11  0.73354215    11  0.80676315    11 -1.12561358
## 12  2    12 -0.40903143    12  1.94155313    12  0.64231119
```

For the moment i came up with this :

```
align2 <- function(df) {
  result <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(j) lapply(1:3, function(i) {x <- df[j,         paste0(c("vpcc", "hpcc"), i)]
                                                                  names(x) <-     paste0(c("vpcc", "hpcc"), (i + (j-1)*4))
                                                                  return(x)}))
  result2 <- lapply(result, function(x) do.call(cbind, x))
  result3 <- do.call(cbind, result2)
  return(result3)
}
testX <- lapply(1:4, function(k) align2(as.data.frame(split(df, f=df$id)[[k]])))
library(plyr)
testX2 <- do.call(rbind.fill, testX)
testX2
##   vpcc1       hpcc1 vpcc2       hpcc2 vpcc3       hpcc3 vpcc4     hpcc4 vpcc5      hpcc5 vpcc6      hpcc6 vpcc7      hpcc7 vpcc8      hpcc8 ...
## 1     1  0.04632267     1 -0.37404379     1  0.90711353     3 1.5245012     3 -1.2153992     3 -1.1241161     4 -0.5062487     4 -0.7598836 ...
## 2     7 -0.10041807     7 -0.17351799     7 -0.03767921     8 0.8168356     8  0.6244916     8  0.5047479     9 -0.4689127     9  1.0774347 ...
## 3     5  1.64610863     5  0.03445275     5 -0.18895338    11 0.7335422    11  0.8067632    11 -1.1256136    NA         NA    NA         NA ...
## 4     2  0.50383152     2  0.06075954     2  0.30690284    NA        NA    NA         NA    NA         NA    NA         NA    NA         NA ...
```

It's a partial solution since it don't keep the id.

But I can't imagine there's not a easier way...

Thank you for suggestions

PS : maybe there's already a solution on SO but I didn't find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the variables `vpcc1` `vpcc2` etc. are redundant, since they have all the same value. So you can transform the dataset into a more economical structure:

```
df <- data.frame(id=sample(1:4, 12, T), vpcc=1:12, hpcc1=rnorm(12),
                 hpcc2=rnorm(12),hpcc3=rnorm(12))
```

Then use `reshape()` and you'll have all the values for each `id` in a single row, with the columns corresponding to the vpcc value, so that `"hpcc3.5"` means `hpcc3` when `vpcc` is `5`.

```
reshape(df, idvar = "id", direction = "wide", timevar = "vpcc")
```

---

**EDIT**:

if `vpccX` varies, then maybe this will give you what you need?

```
df <- data.frame(id=sample(1:4, 12, T), vpcc1=1:12, hpcc1=rnorm(12), vpcc2=1:12,
                 hpcc2=rnorm(12), vpcc3=1:12, hpcc3=rnorm(12))
df$time = ave(df$id, df$id, FUN = function(x) 1:length(x))
reshape(df, idvar = "id", direction = "wide", timevar = "time")
```

of course, you can rename your variables, if it's needed.

Comment: Thx for answering, and no for real vpccX have not the same value, they are date, but i will try with an index.

Comment: OK, that wasn't clear. Check my updated suggestion, maybe it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "same row", is it necessary that the output is like it is in your attempt or would you be happy with something like:

```
x <- aggregate(df[2:ncol(df)],list(df$id),list)
```

which allows you to view output on one row as:

```
x
#  Group.1           vpcc1                                                          hpcc1           vpcc2                                                         hpcc2           vpcc3
#1       1           9, 10                                           1.4651392, 0.8581344           9, 10                                           -1.621135, 1.391945           9, 10
#2       2         1, 3, 7                                  2.784998, 1.667367, -1.329005         1, 3, 7                              0.2115051, 0.7871399, -0.4835389         1, 3, 7
#3       3            5, 6                                          -0.5024987, 0.2822224            5, 6                                            0.155844, 1.336449            5, 6
#4       4 2, 4, 8, 11, 12 -0.48563550, -0.92684024, -0.04016263, -0.41861021, 0.02309864 2, 4, 8, 11, 12 -0.17304058, 0.25428404, -0.49897995, 0.03101927, -0.13529866 2, 4, 8, 11, 12
#                                                          hpcc3
#1                                       -0.05182822, 0.28365514
#2                          -0.06189895, -0.83640652, 0.19425789
#3                                     -0.006440312, 1.378218706
#4 0.09412386, 0.16733125, -1.15198965, -1.00839015, -0.16114475
```

and reference different values of vpcc and hpcc using list notation:

```
x$vpcc1
#$`0`
#[1]  9 10

#$`1`
#[1] 1 3 7

#$`2`
#[1] 5 6

#$`3`
#[1]  2  4  8 11 12

x$vpcc1[[1]]
#[1]  9 10
```

?

Comment: I want the output looks like in my attempt, but i will take a look at your solution. Thx!